# Comppresing folder to zip in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm creating a discord bot in discord.js that saves messages on the server.
I would like to make it send a .zip compressed file from the saved messages folder. **I know how to send attechment but I don't know how to add files from directory to this zip**

I tried this:

**But files aren't appending in zip.

Could someone please send fixed code?

Thank you in advance for your help.**

```js
var fs = require("fs");
var JSZip = require("jszip");
var zip = new JSZip();

zip
   .folder("data");
   .generateNodeStream({ type: 'nodebuffer', streamFiles: true })

  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream("logs.zip"))
   .on('finish', function () {
       console.log("out.zip written.");
   });
```

Comment: Questions here should show the code you tried and explain where you got stuck and exactly what you want help with.  We aren't a coding service that just provides code from scratch.  Instead, we help you solve problem with your code.  So, show your code and explain what exactly in it you want help with.  See [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

At the **Discord.js Documentation** in **stable** version, [TextChannel reference](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/TextChannel) has a method [send](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) that allow send remote and local files.

Sample code of documentation for send a local file:

```js
// Send a local file
channel.send({
  files: [{
    attachment: 'entire/path/to/file.jpg',
    name: 'file.jpg'
    description: 'A description of the file'
  }]
})
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.log);
```

You can build a absolute path file with the [path module](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/path.html) and give as `attachment` value.

```js
const path = require('path');
const ABSOLUTE_PATH_FILE = path.resolve(__dirname, "./../files/filename.zip");
```

Comment: I know how to add attachment but I have a problems with compressing

Comment: The type `blob` should be supported by browser context for `nodejs` you will should use method `generateNodeStream` instead of `generateAsync`  with type `nodebuffer`
can see documentation [how to write zip with JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/howto/write_zip.html)
First party of documentation page contain sample code on *How use in browser* second party explain *How use in NodeJS*

Comment: Thanks this is working! But  **I don't know how to load folder with logs folder to this file**